# Is there a way to create a CRUD as multi-tenancy in ABP.io?

Tags: abp

I want to create a CRUD using the class *CrudAppService<TEntity, TEntityDto, TKey>* but my entity is a *IMultiTenant*. Is there a way it can automatically add this tenant id for me or do I have to overwrite the default CRUD?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At this line
[AbstractKeyCrudAppService.cs#L91](https://github.com/abpframework/abp/blob/41854540464bb8d471c03505c81ffe10d7417923/framework/src/Volo.Abp.Ddd.Application/Volo/Abp/Application/Services/AbstractKeyCrudAppService.cs#L91)

**CrudAppService** tries to set TenantId from `CurrentTenant`. So, If you create a tenant and switch to it, TenantId will be set automatically.